# MVC 5 - Binding a Model and an array of different type of Model in Single View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a project using Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5, EF 6, Visual Basic, Database First Approach.

In my database, I've a table `Employee` as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1), 
    [FirstName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [MiddleName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [LastName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
)
```

Another Table `Qualification` as below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Qualification]
(
    [Id] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1), 
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee,
    [Degree] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Institute] VARCHAR(50) NULL,
)
```

My `Employee` and `Qualification` model look like this:

```
Partial Public Class Employee
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property MiddleName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Overridable Property Qualifications As ICollection(Of Qualification) = New HashSet(Of Qualification)
End Class

Partial Public Class Qualification
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property EmployeeId As Integer
    Public Property Degree As String
    Public Property Institute As String
    Public Overridable Property Employee As Employee
End Class
```

Now, in my view; I want to let the user insert 1 employee alongwith his 5 qualifications at a time: So, my view is like this:

```
@ModelType MyApp.Employee

@Using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, htmlAttributes:= New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.MiddleName, htmlAttributes:= New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.MiddleName, New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.MiddleName, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.LastName, htmlAttributes:= New With { .class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.LastName, New With { .htmlAttributes = New With { .class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.LastName, "", New With { .class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    @For i = 0 To 5
        @<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Degree, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Degree, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Degree, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

        @<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Institute, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Institute, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Qualifications(i).Institute, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

    Next


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
End Using
```

This is how I wrote the action method in the controller:

```
Function Create(<Bind(Include:="Id,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Qualifications")> ByVal employee As Employee) As ActionResult
    ' Code here
End Function
```

Now, when I fill up and submit the form, I get the values I submitted for `Employee` eg. `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName`; but the `Qualifications` count is 0.

I tried to solve the problem using `Tuple` too, but didn't work.

What can I do? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `Bind(Include..` (you binding to all properties and that's the default).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got the solutions, the `Bind` attribute doesn't create a problem! Anyways thanks for help

Comment: No, I know its wasn't the problem - its just completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution myself:

I altered the `Qualifications` property of `Employee` class to:

```
Public Overridable Property Qualifications As List(Of Qualification) = New List(Of Qualification)
```

And it works like a charm!